# error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to build a faster-rcnn model following the instructions given by https://modelzoo.co/model/faster-rcnn-tensorflow

when I try to run the make command inside the lib directory, I got these error

```
/home/hanyikoh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h: In member function ‘void tensorflow::internal::MaybeWith32BitIndexingImpl<Eigen::GpuDevice>::operator()(Func, Args&& ...) const’:
/home/hanyikoh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h:176:25: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’
  176 |     auto all = [](const auto&... bool_vals) {
      |                         ^~~~
/home/hanyikoh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h:176:34: error: expansion pattern ‘const int&’ contains no parameter packs
  176 |     auto all = [](const auto&... bool_vals) {
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~
/home/hanyikoh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h: In lambda function:
/home/hanyikoh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h:177:22: error: ‘bool_vals’ was not declared in this scope
  177 |       for (bool b : {bool_vals...}) {
```

I am running it on a windows machine and on a wsl terminal.
Python version is 3.8.10

Hope someone could give me some hints to resolve this bug, thanks.

Comment: You either need a compiler where default C++14 is default, or somehow add the flag to the compilation command. For the latter, `make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14` might work.

Comment: I try replace the ```make``` with ```make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14``` but still not working for me

Comment: Looking closer at the makefiles in the project, it's hands down among the worst I've seen. The makefile wraps a bash script which does the actual make stuff. The variable isn't communicated downward for what I can see, hence not working. And even then the bash script sets C++11. Which raises the question; what source file are you trying to compile when getting the posted errors? Why are those built? Right now best guess is you're in dependency hell, using 3rd party headers of an incompatible version, but that's not very precise or helpful.

Comment: For a possible one-line fix you can change the `c++11` into `c++14` in `make.sh`.